# How to rewrite a redirected url with haproxy?

Tags: rewrite, haproxy

I'm trying to proxy all requests to /static/pdfs to a cdn that has the same filenames but doesn't have the /static/pdfs prefix. I can do this easily with nginx like this:

```
location ^~ /static/pdfs/ {
  rewrite /static/pdfs/(.*) http://mycdn.com/$1;
}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with haproxy?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use a frontend /backend configuration.  For example:

```
frontend http_proxy
  bind 0.0.0.0:80
  acl is_cnd path_beg /static/pdfs/
  use_backend cdn if is_cdn
  default_backend mysite

backend cdn
  server mycdn.com

backend mysite
  server regular-site.com
```

I'm doing this from memory so it might not be exactly right, but if not then it's pretty close.

Comment: It is pretty close. In fact, it is correct ;)

Comment: No, it is not correct, because it leaves /static/pdfs prefix, which he wants to be removed. I need the same thing :D